# Build error in visual studio C++ community 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

[image: build error image]I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 and I have selected *Development for Desktop* in C++. Everything is installed.

I created a new project like File --> New --> Visual C++ --> Empty project.

After I run the program by clicking *Local Windows Debugger*, I'm getting the following error.

Build error:
[image: build error]

Complete error:
[image: complete error]

I checked the previous questions also but I couldn't find the solution.

Note: I'm not getting Win32 Console Application (File --> New --> Project --> Visual C++ --> Win32 Console Application). I'm getting only Windows Console Application. Even in that also I am getting build error.

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: please click the build error (hyperlink)

Comment: Please show the output window showing the error message you get.

Comment: please find the snap shot

Comment: -1073741515 means: "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135)" Disable Common Language Runtime Support in Project Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1073741515 means: "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135)" Since you do not depend on CLR, Right-click on the project name, and Disable Common Language Runtime Support in Project Properties.

[image]

Comment: i am unable find the same.can you please share the snap shot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting the **Empty Project** for your first experiments with VS2017, select one of the project types that will give you a working skeleton. If you want to try a C++ console app, the project type will be **Windows Console Application**. This will give you a ready-to-run application with an `Main()` function that just has a `return 0;` statement in it.

Hit the **F11** key or select **Debug**/**Step Into** from the menu to compile your project and step into `Main()`. It will stop on the opening curly brace. Hit **F11** again and it will step to the `return 0;` statement. Hit **F5** now and it will continue running and exit the program. Now you have verified that you can successfully build, run, and debug your code.

Once you've verified that this much works, you can start adding code and debug it. The Empty Project is for when you really know what you're doing and want to start from scratch, otherwise one of the predefined projects is a much easier way to get started.

Comment: thanks, but even in other project also i am getting build error while debugging the program. i have attached the screen shot in my question

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I've never seen that specific error, and a Google search for the error doesn't turn up much. (It finds some similar error codes, but I don't see the `-1073741515` error.) Are you trying this with a new **Windows Console Application** with _no_ added or changed code? Try running the app exactly as VS2017 generates it before adding anything. It should run with no problems. If it still gives an error, I wonder if something could be corrupted in your VS2017 installation? That seems unlikely, but if that is what's happening, it might be worth trying uninstalling and reinstalling VS2017.

Comment: i have reinstalled twice but the error is still persist

Comment: And are you trying an _unmodified_ Windows Console Application, straight out of the New Project wizard without any changes?